# C# parse data into CSV without delimiter in quotes

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I need little help with my regex pattern..

I have strings like this

First Line:

```
250;2014-03-01;13:18:31;P25002001873;4006083016590;TCH61159500000;"Ponožky;podkolenky";441;149.00;1.000;;12740000;
```

Second Line:

```
250;2014-03-01;13:18:31;P25002001873;4006083016590;TCH61159500000;"""NORDIC """ ecs;441;149.00;1.000;;12740000;
```

And I need to parse this string by delimiter ;..
With this strings i need to remove ; in first line. ("Ponožky;Podkolenky") But i dont want to delete any other ; because i cannot parse it.

The patter meant to be that remove ; in quotes.. "Ponožky;Podkolenky" => "Ponožky Podkolenky"

Comment: is that 2 lines or 1 in your example string

Comment: Is that the only thing you want removed?

Comment: Yes, only ; in "". I need to because i want to split string with delimiter ;

Comment: @JAttanonRadar: if it is only for this reason, there is a more simple way.

Comment: Maybe it is. But I can't find it.. I found some ways to parse string by delimeter that takes text in quotes as text and not parse it. But solutions what i find not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should neither use Regex, nor reinvent the wheel for this task.

Use Microsofts `TextFieldParser` which supports the parsing of CSV files out of the box:

(It handles as much `;` within your quoted fields as you need).

It is "hidden" inside the `Microsoft.VisualBasic`-Framework, which you simply can import. (Add it as Reference to your Project)

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

//more of the class

using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser("C:\\test\\file.csv"))
{
    parser.CommentTokens = new string[] { "#" };
    parser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { ";" });
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

    //skip headline if there is any
    //parser.ReadLine();

    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

        foreach (String s in fields){
            MessageBox.Show(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Along with the string

```
1;2;3;"A String; with;many;;;semicolons;;;232;";5;"Another;One"
```

Produces the message boxes:

```
1
2
3
A String; with;many;;;semicolons;;;232;
5
Another;One
```

Comment: I just found this framework.. I will probably use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
".*(;).*"
```

This means find a " followed by any characters and then ; and any characters and finally a closing "
with only the ; in a capturing group

Comment: this works for the two given examples, but in my opinion is way to unsave to "parse" data... What if the String is `"Pono;phonp;onemore"`?

Comment: With this it can be done.. I used it like this..                      string[] split = Regex.Match(t, "\".*(;).*\"").Value.Split(';');
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(t, "\".*(;).*\"", string.Join(" ", split)));

Comment: But i think if i used this way to import large data it will be slowing the performance

Answer (score 0):

I will reword your question: **how to split fields of a csv string when the delimiter is present in fields protected with quotes?**

First way: use a csv parser.

Second way: instead of trying to split each items, try to find them.

```
string pat = @"""(?>[^""]+|"""")*""|[^;""]*";
```